# htaccess in a shared hosting

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, shared-hosting

I have a account in a shared hosting(www.1and1.com) and i want a .htaccess redirecting all the request to a different folder. (I'm trying to setup a symfony2 app)

for example, on request to:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/
```

internally respond:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/folder_x/folder_y
```

i already try this(do not work):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /folder_x/folder_y/$1 [R,L]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leading slash isn't matched in `RewriteRule` in `.htaccess`. Change your rule to:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder_x/folder_y/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /folder_x/folder_y%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Some other improvements I have made:

- Removed `R` flag since you wanted internal rewrite only
- Added `RewriteCond` before rule to avoid rewriting URIs that already start with `/folder_x/folder_y/`

Comment: Ok, thanks. 
What i should do if i want to use the rest of the url passed:
e.g:
    www.mydomain.com/something/another_thing
an use it in:
    www.mydomain.com/folder_x/folder_y/something/another_thing

Comment: Oh that is already happening in the current rule, since I am using %{REQUEST_URI} variable in the target.

Comment: ohh, i see, tx again.
But i have another undesired behavior, when i set  www.mydomain.com on the web browser, the browser display this url:  www.mydomain.com/folder_x/folder_y
How can i avoid that and just show www.mydomain.com in the browser?

Comment: It shouldn't happen since I'm using `R` flag above (see my comment also) Do you have other rules also in this .htaccess OR any other .htaccess somewhere? Also try in a different browser.